Prove that a linear transformation exists
I was given the mapping of three different vectors from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$ and have to determine if a linear transformation exists.
If I show that the first two vectors are linearly independent and span $\mathbb{R^2}$ (so they form a base) would that be enough to then argue that a linear transformation exists?
We have also learned that a linear transformation :  →  is uniquely determined by the images of a basis of . So, if the image of the vector $v_3$ can be expressed as a linear combination of the images of the first two basis vectors, does that mean that a linear transformation with these mappings can exist?

The linear transformation will be defined by any two of the vectors but the third may not be correct.


If I show that the first two vectors are linearly independent and span $\mathbb{R}^2$ (so they form a base) would that be enough to then argue that a linear transformation exists?

No it would not. You would also have to check whether the image of the third vector is compatible. Since, say $v_1, v_2$, are a basis $v_3$ is a linear combination of those:
$$v_3 = \lambda_1 v_1 + \lambda_2 v_2$$
So your linear transformation, say $f$, would have to satisfy:
$$f(v_3) = f(\lambda_1 v_1 + \lambda_2 v_2) = \lambda_1 f(v_1) + \lambda_2 f(v_2)$$
If this is true, then there exists a linear transformation which maps according to the images of $v_1,v_2$ and $v_3$.
